Compiling class library with packages
I have this simple class library and I uses csv nuget package.
When I build this project, only ClassLibrary2.dll is in the bin folder. Should it also contain csv.dll file as well?

How to ensure that csv.dll is being copied to bin folder?
I tried to change IncludeAssets value but it didn't work and I got same result.

A fair bit has changed with .Net Core when it comes to builds and deployments. AFAIK to avoid a lot of excessive dependency copying it supports that .deps.json file for resolving dependencies at runtime while debugging. For actual deployments you should be using the Publish feature then selecting between self conained or framework dependent. Both would ensure the csv.dll is copied to the end publish folder.

Did you have any problem when using your library in an actual application? When porting to SDK style projects I did have some issues with missing dependencies in a unit test project, but specifying a <RuntimeIdentifier> in the project file seemed to solve that problem.
